# URLSession downloadTask(with:) creates multiple file downloads

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Background: I have a page where users can go to download various map files. I currently have a solution setup but it has some issues. Here is what I have:

```
public class FileDownloader: NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    public let identifier: String
    public let progress = CurrentValueSubject<Float, Never>(0)
    public let handleFinish: (URL) -> Void
    public let handleError: (Error?) -> Void

    public init(identifier: String, handleFinish: @escaping (URL) -> Void, handleError: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.handleFinish = handleFinish
        self.handleError = handleError
    }

    lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: self.identifier)
        config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)
    }()

    func startDownload(url: URL) {
        let backgroundTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        backgroundTask.resume()
    }

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        self.handleError(error)
    }

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        self.handleFinish(location)
    }

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        let percentage = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

        self.progress.send(percentage)
    }
}
```

Basically I create a new `FileDownloader` for each row file. The problems are the following:

1. On the simulator, I start a download and let it run for a bit, then I stop the app. When I start it again and try to download the file again, it starts downloading 2 of the same file and updates me with the progress of both.
2. I'm not sure how to get the current progress when I go away from the download page and then come back.

Seems like if I could get the currently running task then I could use that. Is it possible to query the system for a running download and start getting the progress updates? Am I way off on my implementation and need to make changes to do what I want to do?

Comment: you need to add the logic to your didCompleteWithError. Something like `if let userInfo = (error as? NSError)?.userInfo,` `let resumeData = userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData] as? Data {`
        `self.resumeData = resumeData`
   `}`

Comment: then `let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(withResumeData: resumeData)` 
`downloadTask.resume()`. Apple has an article about pausing and resuming downloads here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/pausing_and_resuming_downloads

Comment: Not related to your question but thats not how you should observe the progress of your download. You should get the download task progress object and pass it to your UIProgressView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview/1619840-observedprogress

Comment: Leo, how would that work when the app stops? Would I just save the resume data to disk somehow and then load back when I reopen the app? Would `didCompleteWithError` get called in the case of the app stopping?

Comment: Read this article above

Comment: You can cancel your download before your app gets terminated